# How to apply DISTINCT on only date part of datetime field in sqlalchemy python?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, api, datetime, sqlalchemy

I need to query my database and return the result by applying Distinct on only date part of datetime field.

My code is:

```
@blueprint.route('/<field_id>/timeline', methods=['GET'])
@blueprint.response(field_timeline_paged_schema)
def get_field_timeline(
    field_id,
    page=1,
    size=10,
    order_by=['capture_datetime desc'],
    **kwargs
):
    session = flask.g.session    
    field = fetch_field(session, parse_uuid(field_id))
    if field:
        query = session.query(
            func.distinct(cast(Capture.capture_datetime, Date)),
            Capture.capture_datetime.label('event_date'),
            Capture.tags['visibility'].label('visibility')
        ).filter(Capture.field_id == parse_uuid(field_id))
        return paginate(
            query=query,
            order_by=order_by,
            page=page,
            size=size
        )
```

However this returns the following error:

```
(psycopg2.errors.InvalidColumnReference) for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
```

The resulting query is:

```
SELECT distinct(CAST(tenant_resson.capture.capture_datetime AS DATE)) AS distinct_1, CAST(tenant_resson.capture.capture_datetime AS DATE) AS event_date, tenant_resson.capture.tags -> %(tags_1)s AS visibility
FROM tenant_resson.capture
WHERE tenant_resson.capture.field_id = %(field_id_1)s
```

Error is:

```
 Query error - {'error': ProgrammingError('(psycopg2.errors.InvalidColumnReference) SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions\nLINE 2: FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (CAST(tenant_resson.capture.capture...\n                                  ^\n',)
```

How to resolve this issue? Cast is not working for order_by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add order_by to my query. Now it works fine.

```
query = session.query(
            cast(Capture.capture_datetime, Date).label('event_date'),
            Capture.tags['visibility'].label('visibility')
        ).filter(Capture.field_id == parse_uuid(field_id)) \
        .distinct(cast(Capture.capture_datetime, Date)) \
        .order_by(cast(Capture.capture_datetime, Date).desc())
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `sqlalchemy` but this resulting query works as you expect. Please note the DISTINCT ON.
Maybe there is a way in `sqlalchemy` to execute non-trivial parameterized queries? This would give you the extra benefit to be able to test and optimize the query upfront.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (CAST(tenant_resson.capture.capture_datetime AS DATE))
  CAST(tenant_resson.capture.capture_datetime AS DATE) AS event_date,
  tenant_resson.capture.tags -> %(tags_1)s AS visibility
FROM tenant_resson.capture
WHERE tenant_resson.capture.field_id = %(field_id_1)s;
```

You can `order by event_date` if your business logic needs.

Comment: Actually I am looking out for sqlalchemy query.

Answer (score 0):

The query posted by @Stefanov.sm is correct. In SQLAlchemy terms it would be

```py
query = (
    session.query(
        Capture.capture_datetime.label('event_date'),
        Capture.tags['visibility'].label('visibility')
    ).distinct(cast(Capture.capture_datetime, Date))\
    .filter(Capture.field_id == parse_uuid(field_id))
)
```

See [the docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.distinct) for more information